# Does Spinoza Propose that Thought Cannot Aprehend Extension?

Tags: epistemology, spinoza, rationalism

Currently reading *Ethics*, and I understand most of what I have been reading so far, although the epistemology is subtle and hard to understand so I am wondering if this can be cleared up for me.

In *Ethics* by Spinoza, does he claim that the attribute of Thought in humans is unable to understand the attribute of Extension of an object as it exists in-itself? If so, wouldn't this make Spinoza the first modern philosopher to come up with the concept of the in-itself, rather than Kant?

I know that Spinoza mentions the deceiving nature of language and imagination as a *sign* apprehended differently based on the person, and the correlation the mind makes to understand physical objects by their effect, perceived by Thought, on the physical body, in which both Thought and Extension occupy in humans, however it is unclear to me if he sets a clear limitation of the correlate between Thought and Extension.

Comment: As a side note, I find it interesting that Spinoza tries to write that book in the manner of Euclid's Elements, with axioms and proofs via deduction. I'm not sure it works to make the claims more convincing for the modern eye anymore.

Comment: I personally think it is convincing in the sense that given a set of definitions and axioms, so much can necessarily follow from it. However, the presentation in such a format makes it difficult as far as readability and testing whether the retorsion of the propositions are consistent. Beautiful work with many interesting ideas on Metaphysics and Epistemology however. Exceeding expectations.

Comment: Difficult reading indeed, but splendid, yes :-)

Comment: Do you have a particular passage in mind? It seems to me that the "attribute of extension" is opposed to "mind" in the sense that thoughts do not have an attribute of extension. I'm working off the text on Gutenberg: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3800/3800-h/3800-h.htm.

Comment: No, that's why I'm asking the question, if there is a passage which states it definitively. The attribute of mind/thought and the attribute of Extension are two different aspects but I am wondering if in *Ethics* whether Spinoza makes it clear if human thought is able to accurately capture/depict/apprehend extended bodies.

Comment: I searched the text on both "extent/extension" and "mind/thought" but couldn't find a passage that would confirm that so far.

Comment: From Axiom V and Prop III it implies thought can apprehend and thus "cause" extension in some sense while (magically) obviously extension cannot apprehend and "cause" thought. Indeed Kant was not the first philosopher identifying in-itself from phenomena since philosophies related to anti-realistic representationalism from ancient across all cultures especially from the East implicitly contains this distinction. Spinoza here answered this puzzle that except for the Existence there's no illusive things in-themselves and the usual arrow from this illusion to its epi phenomena need be reversed...

Comment: @DoubleKnot "Corollary II.—It follows, secondly, that the ideas, which we have of external bodies, indicate rather the constitution of our own body than the nature of external bodies. I have amply illustrated this in the Appendix to Part I." Also, I believe that your interpretation of Axiom 5 is a misreading as it is only said "We neither feel nor perceive any singular thing, except bodies and modes of thinking" which is clearly not against the noumena/phenomena distinction. Additionally, P3 is "In God there is necessarily an idea, both of his essence and which necessarily follows from it."

Comment: @DoubleKnot So P3 seems to just be about the nature of God, later in this part, Spinoza makes the distinction of the nature of ideas which are from God which are perfect, and those of humans which are allowed to be confused. So this interpretation of yours does not seem to follow from what the text. In my humble opinion.

Comment: I'm referencing part I's axiom and prop, where V reads: *Things which have nothing in common cannot be understood, the one by means of the other; the conception of one does not involve the conception of the other.* Prop III reads: *Things which have nothing in common cannot be one the cause of the other.*

Comment: This is still not convincing to your interpretation, as he also posits the separation of aspects, so this makes sense only in terms of either only in the realm of thought, or only as a positing of the realm of extension. Can you explain more explicitly how these lines support this interpretation?

Comment: My interpretation is that Spinoza here implicitly hinted the subtle *difference* btw these two aspects and even more other aspects such as motion, these attributes aren’t like Hume’s just bundled together. The key seems lies in the realm of thought attribute one can claim apprehension and appreciation of all the other aspects, otherwise why the purely objective cannot apprehend the pure thought?

Comment: Indeed a "white horse" has no doubt the attribute of white, but "horse" as an intersubjective concept of our language game per se is nothing but another attribute of shape which is different from that of a cat while *attributing* nothing *else* at the same time, thus a white horse *is not* a horse at all as the former is a bundle of two attributes while the latter of only one and neither of these attributes can apprehend each other, yet you cannot entirely separate them otherwise then nothing to philosophize about. Ergo the apprehension of thought above is just about *attribute* of extension..

Comment: That's a misinterpretation of Spinoza's definition of *attribute*. This reading of Spinoza is shaky at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a commentary on Spinoza (I think It was by Deleuze) that provides a useful analogy. Think of a cylinder, in xyz we can see it's a volume, but suppose an alien life form who has no concept of 3D and can only see it from it's end (x axis) or side (y axis). Then the volume would appear to it either as a circle (along x) or a rectangle (along y). Yet it is still the same, unique cylinder.

To Spinoza, Attributes are similar in the sense that one thing can be considered either as Extension or as Idea, but it is still the same one thing. Actually, it has an infinite number of attributes (as it is part of the Substance, that has infinite attributes) but we mere humans can only conceive of it either as Extension or Idea.

Spinoza specifies that Extention can't affect Ideas and vice versa, but both attributes should be seen as affected simultaneously, each in their own regard. It is to say, when rays of sun (extension) affect my body, the idea of them also affects my spirit.

Here we can see that the relation between Extension and Idea is fundamentally different from the relation between Noumenon and Phenomenon. Extension and ideas are two ways to consider the same thing, while Noumenon *is* the thing and Phenomenon merely the way it affects us.

Spinoza introduces the concept of *adequate* ideas, which is to say an idea that matches with the thing it's related to. For exemple, if a friend I trust is found to lie to me, it is because my idea of him was *inadequate* i.e. I thought he was truthful when he was not. Therefore I shouldn't blame him but try to understand why I had this wrong idea and correct myself ("non ridere, non lugere, neque detestari, sed intelligere", a central tenet of the *Ethics*).

Although this idea of false representation is present in Spinoza's philosophy, I don't recall that he ever states adequate ideas to be inaccessible *in theory*. Of course, as our senses are fallible and our intellect limited, it is doubtful that we can ever have an adequate idea of very complex or big things (imagine someone knowing everything there is to know about the New York metro system, or a specific instance of a Saturn V rocket). But it's a degree of knowledge Spinoza definitely think we should tend towards, rather than "just give up, not possible" type of stance. In other words, adequate ideas *might be* inaccessible for practical reason, while noumenon *is* definitely inaccessible for metaphysical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a passage that may be relevant, in a Note on Prop VII in Part 2:

> Before going any further, I wish to recall to mind what has been
> pointed out above—namely, that whatsoever can be perceived by the
> infinite intellect as constituting the essence of substance, belongs
> altogether only to one substance: consequently, substance thinking and
> substance extended are one and the same substance, comprehended now
> through one attribute, now through the other. So, also, a mode of
> extension and the idea of that mode are one and the same thing, though
> expressed in two ways. This truth seems to have been dimly recognized
> by those Jews who maintained that God, God's intellect, and the things
> understood by God are identical. For instance, a circle existing in
> nature, and the idea of a circle existing, which is also in God, are
> one and the same thing displayed through different attributes. Thus,
> whether we conceive nature under the attribute of extension, or under
> the attribute of thought, or under any other attribute, we shall find
> the same order, or one and the same chain of causes—that is, the same
> things following in either case.

My comment, especially given the last sentence would be that Spinoza says that it is the same chain of causes, i.e. there is no difference, if you understand nature as ideas or actually extent. My very bold and personal extrapolation would be that he would reject the distinction between noumena and phenomena as making no difference (and of course, he doesn't have that frame of reference). Maybe there is the germ of a noumena/phenomena distinction here, but (according to my own very bold interpretation), Spinoza seems to not be interested in it.

Comment: Hmm, later in the chapter, Spinoza states this "Corollary II.—It follows, secondly, that the ideas, which we have of external bodies, indicate rather the constitution of our own body than the nature of external bodies. I have amply illustrated this in the Appendix to Part I."

Comment: @TCoff So this would indicate that he stops at "ideas" that are on the side of the subject, but doesn't think that there are necessarily external bodies (no things in thermselves?)

Comment: @TCoff Maybe I have to take it back, and there seems to be "ideas that are expressions in thought of states of the body" and "adequate ideas" that reveal the essence of things (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spinoza/#Know). It doesn't quite feel like noumena/phenomena yet, but it's in the direction, and Spinoza seems to do something different with it?

Comment: Yes it is quite confusing, it seems that he both posits the noumena/phenomenon while also denies it under the condition of adequacy (which is coherent theory of knowlege?) Maybe this is his position as such, that there is a noumena/phenomena division unless the description of the object is an idea under the coherent theory of truth.